# Is it possible to change the name of the `prototype` property of JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript

First off, I understand that this is wildly inadvisable for most practical JS applications. I'm building a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and am just testing the limits of JavaScript (which seem to be expanding with new features like [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and [reflection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect)).

Say I create a new function: `var a = function(){}` but for some crazy reason I *really* want to use the `prototype` property of `a` to store some arbitrary data (`a.prototype = "blah"`).

The [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors) of `Function.prototype` is this:

```
configurable: false
enumerable: false
writable: true
```

So it's easy enough to overwrite it, but that'll mess with the functionality of the function. Calling `new a()` won't behave as it should. Ideally there'd be a way to rename it to `__prototype` or something like that, and have the constructor reference that property rather than `prototype` when it's creating a new instance.

My suspicion is that this is impossible, but I'm not sure if ES6 has added anything that might make this feasible (proxies)? It'd be great if a JavaScript pro who understands what's going on under the hood could help out with this.

P.S. I'd also like to do the same with `Function.arguments`, but that might be a separate question because `arguments` isn't `configurable` or `writable`. Any comments there?

Comment: I think it's kind of *hardcoded* in ES standard. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-prototype .

Comment: You can make your own create function which uses `Object.create` to create an object with prototype set to `__prototype` property, but default *new* will always look for `.prototype` in constructor

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Audrey!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the name of the `prototype` property of JavaScript functions?

If you mean, is it possible to update the behavior of the `new` operator such that it uses a different property to assign the new object's prototype rather than `a.prototype` when you use `new a`, no, it isn't. But you're right that you could create a proxy for `a` (say, `pa`) such that `new pa` would set a different prototype for the new object.

Example (I've used `A` and `PA` since this is a constructor function), see comments:

```js
// Our original constructor
function A(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
// A different property to use as a prototype
A.objectPrototype = {
  sayName() {
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}`);
  }
};
// Make the prototype property something else entirely
A.prototype = 42;

// Construct our proxy
const PA = new Proxy(A, {
  construct(target, args, newTarget) {
    let o = Reflect.construct(target, args, newTarget);
    // Replace the object's prototype
    Object.setPrototypeOf(o, A.objectPrototype);
    return o;
  }
});

// Demonstrate that the new object gets its prototype from our custom prop
const o = new PA("foo");
o.sayName();
```

`new A` still won't do it, and `PA` won't play properly with inheritance, and I would **strongly recommend** not doing it, but yeah, Proxies are powerful. :-)

> So it's easy enough to overwrite it, but that'll mess with the functionality of the function.

Only if you use the function with the `new` operator. If you don't, you can do whatever you want with the `prototype` property as it won't be used for anything. (I *wouldn't*, but you can.)

Comment: Thanks, TJ! I appreciated the fast response - very thorough and helpful as usual.